# insert data array using model table in database mvc c#

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, oracle, model-view-controller

Can you fix my problem? I try to insert data in table database oracle, but the data take from session array. 
this code controller to insert data

```
int[] NoId = (int[])Session["Id"];
string[] NamaBarang = (string[])Session["namaBarang"];
string[] HargaSatuan = (string[])Session["harga"];
string[] JumlahBarang = (string[])Session["jumlah"];
string[] HargaTotal = (string[])Session["total"];
string[] Diskon = (string[])Session["disc"];
string[] DPP = (string[])Session["Dpp"];
string[] PPN = (string[])Session["Ppn"];

MPMISTAX_DTLMASUK itemA = new MPMISTAX_DTLMASUK();
itemA.KD_PPN = "2";
itemA.KDUNIT = Kategori;
itemA.KODE_SUPP = "M2Z";
itemA.NOFAK = nomorFaktur;
itemA.KDFAK = kodeFaktur;
itemA.VKODECABANG = KodeMain;
item.TAHUN = TanggalFak.Year;
itemA.RETUR = "";
itemA.NMBRG = NamaBarang[0];
itemA.HRGSAT = HargaSatuan[0];
itemA.NPWP = npwpPenjual;
itemA.NODOK = "-";

dbContext.MPMISTAX_DTLMASUK.Add(itemA);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I try using that code, but its error. I Hope you can help my problem. Thank you

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: itemA.NMBRG type data is long, but session array NamaBarang[0] type data is string, and can I insert data array in table database  ?

Comment: You will have to loop through array to insert into database.

Comment: Can you give me example? I don't have any idea, because I still new learning about mvc and oracle database

Answer (score 1):

What is the datatype of

**itemA.NMBRG**?

if it's long please convert the **NamaBarang[0]** to long datatype before assigning. Like

**itemA.NMBRG = (long)NamaBarang[0];**

Hope this helps!!

Comment: the datatype of itemA.NMBRG is string, same of NamaBarang[0], but the problem is datatype of itemA.HRGSAT. that is long and the HargaSatuan[0] is string. I can't convert because the string include " . " not only character. and convert to long not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign `string` to a feild which is of type `long` .Parse the `string` to `long` for feild `NMBRG`.

```
itemA.NMBRG = (long)NamaBarang[0];
```

Comment: thank, that work, but you can help me, how can I Insert data array in table database?

Comment: You have to insert two arrays ?

Comment: Can you give me example with code? because I don't know how to explain that. My mind is blank. I Hope you can help me?

Comment: I have one more question ? How is that string include " . " not only character?

Comment: `Strings` are enclosed in double qoutes. Length of `NamaBarang` and `HargaSatuan` will be same ?

Comment: not double quotes, but like this. example HargaSatuan = 123001.77 and how can I convert to long? its not work when I try "Convert.ToInt64" ?

Comment: No this is a `decimal` not a `long` so you need to convert to `decimal`

Comment: I just follow the type on database, because not me who makes the table of database. and the datatype in database is long not decimal. how can I change the datatype?

Comment: Then you should have a consistent structure.